# postgresql: использование IF или CASE для выбора хранимую функцию из которой производить выборку

Tags: sql, postgresql, if, case, хранимые-процедуры

есть такая начинка функции:

```
SELECT
    f.id AS id, 
    t.name AS name
FROM 
    func1(param1) AS f
    LEFT JOIN table AS t ON t.id = f.id
```

есть параметр функции `param2 integer`

как сделать так, чтобы если `param2 = 0`, то в запросе использовалась бы функция `func1`, а если `param2 = 1`, то функция `func2`?

```
SELECT
    f.id AS id, 
    t.name AS name
FROM 
    func1(param2) AS f
    LEFT JOIN table AS t ON t.id = f.id
```

понимаю, что можно сделать через динамический запрос, т.е. сначала в виде текста будет сформирован запрос

```
'SELECT
    f.id AS id, 
    t.name AS name
FROM 
    ' || func_name || '(param1) AS f
    LEFT JOIN table AS t ON t.id = f.id'
```

но можно ли сделать более просто - напрямую?

Comment: Как вариант, сделать функцию обертку, которая будет вызывать нужную функцию, в зависимости от переданных параметров.